# How to use SwiftUI LazyVGrid to build a compact grid?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Expected layout

[image]

Instead, only got this layout from SwiftUI

[image]

There is empty space in between the cell and it's not compact. It doesn't behave like CSS flex system.

The closest I can find is this library but it doesn't do lazy load:

https://github.com/exyte/Grid/